# How to populate javafx tableview with a hashmap or any List instead of observable list in following format

Tags: java, list, tableview, javafx-2, javafx

How can I just use a `List` , `ArrayList` or `HashMap` in the the observable list where it uses `<Person>` and every time a new `Person()` initialization and same for table column `PropertyValueFactory`.

How can I just use :

```
 private final ObservableList<Person> data =
    FXCollections.observableArrayList( MyList/HashMap/ArrayList Here);
```

I am having a tough time to figure out where I am making a mistake.

Oracle docs give an example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm)

```
private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
        new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
        new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
        new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
        new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com"));


TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
    emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
    emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));

    table.setItems(data);
```

Here is my code:

```
      @FXML
      private TableView<ObservableList> tableViewCOA = new TableView<ObservableList>();

      @FXML
      private TableColumn superTypeNameCol = new TableColumn();

      @FXML
      private TableColumn catagoryNameCol = new TableColumn();

      @FXML
      private TableColumn accountNameCol = new TableColumn();
      @FXML
      private TableColumn accountIDCol = new TableColumn();

  final ObservableList<ObservableList> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(

        getAllCOA() //<-- myObservableListHere (refer to last method of jdbc)

          );

          superTypeNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
          new PropertyValueFactory<COA,String>("superNameCol")
              );

          catagoryNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
          new PropertyValueFactory<COA,String>("catagoryNameCol")
              );
          accountIDCol.setCellValueFactory(
          new PropertyValueFactory<COA,String>("accountIDCol")
              );
          accountNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
          new PropertyValueFactory<COA,String>("accountNameCol")
              );

          tableViewCOA.setItems(data);

  /*
  * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
  * and open the template in the editor.
  */
  package accountsMain;

  import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

  /**
  *
  * @author u1
  */
  public class COA{


      private final SimpleStringProperty superNameCol;
      private final SimpleStringProperty catagoryNameCol;
      private final SimpleStringProperty accountNameCol;
      private final SimpleStringProperty accountIDCol;


      public COA(String superName,
          String catagoryName,
        String accountName,
        String accountID

          ){


      this.superNameCol   = new SimpleStringProperty(superName);
      this.catagoryNameCol  = new SimpleStringProperty(catagoryName);
      this.accountIDCol  = new SimpleStringProperty(accountID);
      this.accountNameCol   = new SimpleStringProperty(accountName);

      }

      public String getSuperNameCol() {
        return superNameCol.get();
      }
      public void setSuperNameCol(String superName) {
      superNameCol.set(superName);
      }

      public String getCatagoryNameCol() {
        return catagoryNameCol.get();
      }
      public void setCatagoryNameCol(String catagoryName) {
      catagoryNameCol.set(catagoryName);
      }

      public String getAccountIDCol() {
        return accountIDCol.get();
      }
      public void setAccountIDCol(String accountID) {
      accountIDCol.set(accountID);
      }

      public String getAccountNameCol() {
        return accountNameCol.get();
      }
      public void setAccountNameCol(String accountName) {
      accountNameCol.set(accountName);
      }
      }

  ///////////////////////////// this is what returns -----myObservableList-------///////////////////////////////

  public static ObservableList<ObservableList> getAllCOA() {

          Connection con = null;

      //    HashMap rows = new HashMap();
          ObservableList<ObservableList> rows = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

      try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          con = DriverManager.getConnection(
              "jdbc:mysql://"+host+":3306/"+DBname, user, password);


          PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement(
        "select "
              + "supercoa.superTypeName,"
              + "catagorycoa.catagoryName,"
              + "accountscoa.accountName,"
              + "accountscoa.account_id"
              + " FROM"
              + " supercoa,catagorycoa,accountscoa"
              + " WHERE"
              + " accountscoa.catagory_id = catagorycoa.catagory_id"
              + " group by accountscoa.accountName");

          ResultSet rs = null;
          rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
          int i = 1;
          while (rs.next()) {

        //  List singleRow = new ArrayList();
          ObservableList<String> singleRow = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
          String supertypeName = rs.getString("supertypeName");  singleRow.add(supertypeName);
          String catagoryName = rs.getString("catagoryName");  singleRow.add(catagoryName);
          String accountName = rs.getString("accountName");  singleRow.add(accountName);
          String account_id = rs.getString("account_id");  singleRow.add(account_id);

          //rows.put(i,singleRow);
          //i++;
          rows.add(singleRow);
          }

          pStmt.close();
          con.close();

          } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
          main.ErrorLogging.errorLog(e.toString());

          } 
        return rows;
      }
```

The data doesn't appears, but the table shows with blank columns

Comment: @jewelsea iam waiting for an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To populate a TableView from a HashMap, see the TableView tutorial section [Adding Maps of Data to the Table](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm).

---

For the example you have provided in your question, it is probably best to change the signature of the `getAllCOA()` method to:

```
public static ObservableList<COA> getAllCOA()
```

Also, when you use the `getAllCOA()` method, instead have:

```
final ObservableList<COA> data = getAllCOA();
```

And when you define your table, use instead:

```
private TableView<COA> tableViewCOA = new TableView<COA>();
```

In this way you will be working with a list of COA objects, rather than just a list of lists.  This will allow the cell value factories you have created to work.  Your cell value factories are not working currently because they are built to introspect on the properties of a COA object and you are not placing COA objects in your table data.

Comment: GREAT answer ! Thanks . I think I can also add a text box or checkbox or some other GUI control inside a cell/ column  by the cell factory? do tell me if you have tutorial or hint. Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe I would like a mixture of Map data and GUI components with full control. I am confused how to integrate <COA> (the table model seperate class that I made) with HashMap

Answer (score 0):

Try to do type casting

```
private final ObservableList<Person> data = (ObservableList<Person>)
    FXCollections.observableArrayList( MyList/HashMap/ArrayList Here);
```

Comment: do I really need <Person>? do i really need a seperate class Person.java and set my column model there?

Comment: secondly, my HashMap has an arraylist as value on each key. and that array list has the individual column values. e.g  hashmap's first value on first key would be arraylist of strings having "column1 value", "colume2 value", "so on"      and same for the second row.

Comment: the data doesnt appears, but the table shows with blank columns

Comment: i have edited the question and added my code. please have a look.

Comment: I guess you need to spent some times to learn [java generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html). Worth to know.